# NixOS create DB (mysql, mariadb)

Tags: mariadb, nix, nixos

Trying to create a database during system configuration. I am attaching the contents of the configuration.nix file below. After running the `sudo nixos-rebuild switch` command, the mariadb service is started, the database and the user with the given password are created. However, the database is empty, although I expect the contents of the main.sql file to be written to the database.

configuration.nix

```
let
 statsConfig = {
    db = "test1";
    user = "stats";
    password = "1";
  };
in
{
services.mysql = {
    package = pkgs.mariadb;
    enable = true;
    ensureDatabases = [
      statsConfig.db
    ];
   replication.role = "master";
       replication.slaveHost = "127.0.0.1";
       replication.masterUser = "${statsConfig.user}";
       replication.masterPassword = "${statsConfig.password}";
       initialDatabases = [{ name = "${statsConfig.db}";   schema = ./main.sql;  }];
       initialScript = ./main.sql;
    ensureUsers = [
      {
        name = "${statsConfig.user}";
        ensurePermissions = {
          "${statsConfig.db}.*" = "ALL PRIVILEGES";
        };
      }
    ];

};


systemd.services.setdbpass = {
    description = "MySQL database password setup";
    wants = [ "mariadb.service" ];
    wantedBy = [ "multi-user.target" ];
    serviceConfig = {
      ExecStart = ''
      ${pkgs.mariadb}/bin/mysql -e "grant all privileges on ${statsConfig.db}.* to ${statsConfig.user}@localhost identified by '${statsConfig.password}';" ${statsConfig.db}
      '';
      User = "root";
      PermissionsStartOnly = true;
      RemainAfterExit = true;
    };
 };


}
```

main.sql

```
create table tests
( Id   INTEGER      NOT NULL,
  Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  primary key(Id)
);

insert into tests values (1, 'a');
```

Answer (score 2):

You main.sql is not being copied to the /nix/store , so it won't be able to find it.

https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/vlktomas/nix-examples/-/blob/web/Laravel/laravel/cd.nix?L112&subtree=true

and

https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/tumblr/jetpants/-/blob/testing/packages/mysql-container/service.nix?L114&subtree=true

has example how it can be used.